# Not Enough Space to Show Ads On Custom Dialog Android Issue

Tags: android

I'm having a problem with showing ads from Admob on my custom dialog. It says not enough space to show ad, needs 320x50dp and it has 294x250dp. I'm using a custom dialog such as this one:

[image]

I believe that the problem is in the dialog itself, as it has empty space on left and right size, but I'm not sure how to solve it. I'm asking for any type of advice that could help me to show ad properly. 
Below is my xml code where adview is present:
http://pastebin.com/pHYbjtU1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used an ordinary layout instead of a dialog, and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.kaladont.PostGameScreen"
    android:gravity="center"

    >

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:minWidth="320dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/levelselectorbg"

        >

        <com.example.classes.FontImageButton
            android:id="@+id/nextLvlButton"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Next level"
            />

        <com.example.classes.MyTextView
            android:id="@+id/notifyTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="55sp"
            android:text="Congrats!"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            />

        <com.example.classes.FontImageButton
            android:id="@+id/mainMenuButton"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/nextLvlButton"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/nextLvlButton"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="Main Menu" />

        <com.example.classes.MyTextView
            android:id="@+id/scoreTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/notifyTV"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/gameGoalTV"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:textSize="33sp"
            android:text="Your score is: "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            />

        <com.example.classes.MyTextView
            android:id="@+id/gameGoalTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/scoreTV"
            android:layout_below="@+id/notifyTV"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:text=""
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            />

        <com.example.classes.FontImageButton
            android:id="@+id/restartButton"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/nextLvlButton"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/nextLvlButton"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Restart"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView

        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-5651680025356127/9525960691 "
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It won't work, i get the next message: "Not enough space to show ad, needs 320x50dp, but only has 0x508dp"

Comment: add these to the parent Linear layout
android:paddingLeft="0"
android:paddingRight="0"
and make the Adview like this
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Comment: I get the same response, it needs 320x50dp, but only has 0x508dp. I'm pretty sure that the problem is that the dialog does not fill the width of the device and it only has 297dp, but for the showing of the banner it needs 320dp. I'm just not sure how to expand the width of the dialog.

Comment: Did you try on a bigger screen emulator, because I think the one you're testing on is too small